# Is there a Check Out/In option for Sharepoint 2013 for individual rows of data (records) not documents?

Tags: check-out, check-in

We have created a database in SharePoint and are using InfoPath 2013 for entering or changing the data.  So, lets say Each row of data or "record" has multiple fields such as: 1) ID 2) Status 3) Status Date 4) User namde, etc.  Is there a Check Out/In function that can be used per row of data?

Comment: No such option out of the box. Why do you need? Perhaps there is another way to solve the need.

Answer (score 0):

You can check in/check out files in SharePoint. There is no concept of check in/check out of list items. You can enable versioning on the list to retain major versions of the items if you are concerned about being able to roll back data. This is enable in the list settings, Versioning settings.

Answer (score 0):

The (Check In/Out) is associated with the document library content types so that is only found in libraries. Perhaps you could mimic this with a choice column that has (In/Out) as choices. The only thing you loose is the lock that assigns it to a person until they check it back in.